# Error with pointing to correct python version: virtualenvwrapper.sh

Tags: python, virtualenv

I get this error when I boot up terminal:

```
Last login: Thu Apr  9 19:49:08 on ttys001
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
dhcp-128-189-78-23:~ user_me$
```

I need to "point" my virtual environment to the version of python I'm using.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same exact issue and updating my path didn't help anything, nor did setting VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON and VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV. This is because I was seeing this strange behavior when running my version of python:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.executable
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

I was able to fix everything by uninstalling python with brew, reinstalling python with brew, and forcing it to overwrite existing symlinks in /usr/local/bin.

```
brew uninstall --force python
brew install python
brew link --overwrite python
brew linkapps python
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
sudo pip uninstall virtualenv
pip install virtualenv
sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Hopefully you were able to get past this issue when you encountered it six months ago. I wanted to post my solution in case others run in to the same issue and cannot solve it by setting their paths and env variables.

Answer (score 28):

The following was found in the [virtualenvwrapper install guide](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html). You could try this to set up your $PATH correct.

To override the $PATH search, set the variable VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON to the full path of the interpreter to use and VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV to the full path of the virtualenv binary to use. Both variables must be set before sourcing virtualenvwrapper.sh. For example:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: Once I removed local it's working fine in Ubuntu 20. Just update your comment.  "export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python"

Comment: This should've been the accepted answer as this does not require uninstalling any system packages.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use brew install multi version python, but i use the native python created virtualenv, as i've updated my mac os version, something wrong happened. I can not get my virtualenv work with below error.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
```

Things i've done make my environment back.

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python get-pip.py
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -m pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I got this error after a series of steps, the first was to install `wormhole` (https://magic-wormhole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/welcome.html#example) which installed Python 3.8.
I started having other errors which I resolved doing a `brew uninstall python@2`

```
brew uninstall python@2
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_2... (4,814 files, 84.8MB)
python@2 HEAD_3 is still installed.
Run `brew uninstall --force python@2` to remove all versions.

brew uninstall --force python@2
Uninstalling python@2... (822B)
```

At this point the error in this question appeared:

```
Last login: Wed May 27 11:33:08 on ttys025
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

My solution was to :

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 neo  admin  34 Nov 27 16:46 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.5/bin/python3


ln -s ../Cellar/python/3.7.5/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Now the error seems to be gone.
I am not sure if this is a good solution, I am interested in the feedback of those people who understand/know `brew` better than me.